# MatLab: Code for a sparse version of Horner's rule

Tags: matlab

I have written code to evaluate polynomials

> p(x)=a_0+x(a_1+x(a_2+x(a_3+...+x(a_(n-1)+xa_n)...)))
>    using Horner's rule as follows

```
function [answer ] = Simple( a,x )
%Simple takes two arguments that are in order and returns the value of the
%polynomial p(x). Simple is called by typing Simple(a,x)
% a is a row vector
%x is the associated scalar value
n=length(a);
result=a(n);
if (any(a~=floor(a))
   error('The values in a must be integers')
end
for j=n-1:-1:1 %for loop working backwards through the vector a  
   result=x*result+a(j);
end
   answer=result;
end
```

I am now trying to write a code for a sparse version of this ie

> p(x)=x^(i_1)(b_1+x^((i_2)-(i_1))(b_2+x^((i_3)-(i_2))(b_3+...+x^((i_(k-1))-(i_(k-2)))(b_(k-1)+x^((i_k)-(i(k-1)))b_k)...)))

I think I need the inputs to be a row vector of `i` and a row vector of b and a scalar value `x`. Any ideas where I can find this? I am unsure how to code it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to answer this is to look at an intermediate term in `p(x)`,
this will be

```
...(b_j + x^(i_(j+1) - i_j)(...
```

instead of the usual `...(a_j + x(...`, thus you need to change the line `result=x*result+a(j);`.

Also there is a slight flaw in your formula for `p(x)`, it should be `p(x) = x^(i_1 - 1)(...`, this comes from the fact that `p(x) = a_1 x^0 + a_2 x^1 + ... + a_n x^(n-1)` which comes from the fact that indexes of matrices in Matlab start at 1 instead of 0.  Here is the full code

```
function [answer ] = SparseHorner( a,x )
% SparseHorner takes two arguments that are in order and returns the value of the
% polynomial p(x). SparseHorner is called by typing SparseHorner(a,x)
% a is a sparse row vector
% x is the associated scalar value

%// Find the entries where a is nonzero
[xInd yInd aVal] = find(a);
if any(aVal~=floor(aVal))
   error('The values in a must be integers')
end

%// a is a row vector so only yInd's values change
ind = yInd;

result=aVal(end);
%// for loop working backwards through the vector a  
%// numel is better than length
for j=(numel(ind)-1):-1:1 
   %// a(ind(j)) is much slower than aVal(j)
   result=x^(ind(j+1)-ind(j))*result + aVal(j);
end

answer=result*x^(ind(1)-1);
end
```

Note that this treats `a` differently than Matlab's `polyval`, the latter has `p(x) = a_1 x^n + ... + a_n`; if you want to be consistent, then add the line `a = fliplr(a)` near the beginning of the function.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The formula for p(x) in my question it the one i've been given to work from. i'm sure i need my in put to be Sparse(index,b,x) I have written the following but i think there is an error with it

 `function [answer] = Sparse(index,b,x)

n=length(index);
m=length(b);
if(m~=n)
    error('The length of the vector b must be equal to that of index')
end
indicies=index(n)-index(n-1);
result=b(m-1)+b(m)*myexpt(x,indicies);

for j=m-2:-1:1
    result=b(j)+myexpt(x,indicies)*result;
end
answer=result;


end`

myexpt is a separate function to evaluate x the power of something